# HIVE: Error in GROUP BY Key

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
hive -e "select a.EMP_ID,
       count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR) as NUM_CURRENT_EMP,
       count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR)/count(distinct a.SERIAL_NBR) as DISTINCT_EMP
from   ORDERS_COMBINED_EMPLOYEES as a
inner  join ORDERS_EMPLOYEE_STATS as b
         on a.CPP_ID = b.CPP_ID
left   join (   select SERIAL_NBR, MIN(TRAN_DT) as TRAN_DT
                from   EMP_TXNS
                group  by SERIAL_NBR
            ) c
         on c.SERIAL_NBR = a.SERIAL_NBR
where    c.TRAN_DT > a.LAST_TXN_DT
group by a.EMP_ID
having ( 
          (NUM_CURRENT_EMP >= 25 and DISTINCT_EMP > 0.01)
       ) ; " > EMPLOYEE_ORDERS.txt
```

Getting error message,
 `"FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 15:31 Expression not in GROUP BY key '0.01'".`
When I ran the same query with just one condition in `HAVING` clause as `NUM_CURRENT_EMP >= 25`, the query ran fine without any issues. `NUM_CURRENT_EMP`  is a `int` type and `DISTINCT_EMP` is `float` in the table where I am trying to insert the results. Breaking my head.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you're missing a right parentheses between `DISTINCT_EMP > 0.01)` and `;`

Comment: @Jim As the condition 'NUM_CURRENT_EMP >= 25' alone is working fine I just replaced it with condition, DISTINCT_EMP >= 25. Then I am getting the same error as "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 15:31 Expression not in GROUP BY key '25'". I think it has something to do with this select statement itself count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR)/count(distinct a.SERIAL_NBR as DISTINCT_EMP. Now I am trying to just pull count(distinct a.CARD_SK) in the first go. And then will do DISTINCT_EMP ratio calculation in another go. I hope this will work.

Comment: Ok, I was just noticing that this block of code `having ( 
          (NUM_CURRENT_EMP >= 25 and DISTINCT_EMP > 0.01)
        ; ` has two opening parentheses and only one closing parentheses.

Comment: @Jim Its a typo mistake while pasting it here. I edited it now. While running the query, I ran it properly with paranthesis closed.

Comment: I wonder if it thinks that 0.01 is a field.  What happens if you replace 0.01 with just 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you replace the aliases in the `having` with the expressions that define them?

```
having count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR) >= 25 and
       count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR)/count(distinct a.SERIAL_NBR) > 0.01
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff it worked. But I thought Alias also will work. I think the problem might be with selecting count(distinct c.SERIAL_NBR)/count(distinct a.SERIAL_NBR) as an Alias. Might be the Computation portion is creating problem.